# rails 3.1 asset pipeline routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

This has been asked many times before, but nothing that I've tried has worked, and I've been trying to resolve it for two days now.

I'm trying to migrate my app to rails 3.1 because I'm starting to use backbone and coffeescript and figured it made sense to just upgrade the whole thing.

I've followed the railscast, been through tons of blogs, etc. etc. No luck, at the point I'm not even trying to load the backbone pages, jquery itself isn't being loaded.

I try to navigate to localhost:3000/assets and get 

No route matches [GET] "/assets"

the output of Rails.application.config.assets.paths is

```
["/media/sf_Ruby192/mysite/app/assets/images", "/media/sf_Ruby192/mysite/app/assets/javascripts", "/media/sf_Ruby192/mysite/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/home/pete/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/cocoon-1.0.15/app/assets/javascripts", "/home/pete/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/formtastic-2.0.2/app/assets/stylesheets", "/home/pete/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.19/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/home/pete/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/admin_data-1.1.16/app/assets/images", "/home/pete/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/admin_data-1.1.16/app/assets/javascripts", "/home/pete/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/admin_data-1.1.16/app/assets/stylesheets"]
```

So this leads me to believe that the assets paths are set-up correctly.

Any suggestions here? I am running this in a virtualbox on windows, hence the path from root being /media/sf_Ruby192, which is the path on windows.

The manifest file is

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Are you able to edit the question and post the contents of your manifest files?

Comment: @RichardHulse I've updated the question to include the manifest file, but I was really just taking that from the examples.

Comment: I just upgraded to rails 3.1.3 and the problem seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have fixed the problem but for future reference it is useful to point out:

When you are in development mode, `localhost:3000/assets` will always render a No route error.

Comment: you are correct Phil, however, pointing it to the application.js file will return a result. I was thinking I'd get the folder view through the assets route.